# JSON/XML vs HTTP GET/POST

Tags: xml, json, http

I am developing an android application where users will fill in profile details and click submit.

On submit, should I store data in a json object or simple use get or post and how to decide between the two?

Comment: Please elaborate. If you need basic information on how to create and use webservices you might be interested in doing some google searches for "REST HowTo Java" - but I am already guessing that you will use java, as you did not explicitly state the language you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we lack some informations about what you are really trying to achieve here and specially we don't know about your front/back (client/server) architecture. Nevertheless, here are some hints to help you.

JSON object is just a way to represent your data in your client before you decide what to do with it. IT could be XML or any other format. JSON is quite handy because they are many tools/api using it.

Then get/post are http verbs that your client can use to get/send informations/data to the server. If a user is on your site and wants to register profile data, then what you need to do in the android app (the client) is a POST with the JSON (for example) data as body of this request that targets the server. Then server is waiting for connection on this endpoint and will store the data and send an OK status (like 201).

Comment: You answered my question. ;)